# Prefetching in Nvidia CUDA

Tags: cuda, nvidia, prefetch

I'm working on data prefetching in nVidia CUDA. I read some documents on prefetching on device itself i.e. Prefetching from shared memory to cache.

But I'm interested in data prefetching between CPU and GPU. Can anyone connect me with some documents or something regarding this matter. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your question is way too broad in its current form - try asking a more specific question. You might also want to check out the nVidia developer forums at http://developer.nvidia.com.

Comment: Ok..how can  I add prefetch instruction in given CUDA program??

Comment: This is still very vague - prefetch what to what exactly ? For what purpose ? On what generation of GPU ?

Answer (score 1):

Answer based on your comment:

> when we to want perform computation on large data ideally we'll send max data to GPU,perform computation,send it back to CPU i.e SEND,COMPUTE,SEND(back to CPU) now whn it sends back to CPU GPU has to stall,now my plan is given CU program,say it runs in entire global mem,i'll compel it to run it in half of the global mem so that rest of the half i can use for data prefetching,so while computation is being performed in one half simultaneously i cn prefetch data in otherhalf.so no stalls will be there..now tell me is it feasible to do?performance will be degraded or upgraded?should enhance..

CUDA *streams* were introduced to enable exactly this approach.

If your compoutation is rather intensive, then yes --- it can greatly speed up your performance. On the other hand, if data transfers take, say, 90% of your time, you will save only on computation time - that is - 10% tops...

The details, including examples, on how to use streams is provided in CUDA Programming Guide.
For version 4.0, that will be section "3.2.5.5 Streams", and in particular "3.2.5.5.5 Overlapping Behavior" --- there, they launch another, asynchronous memory copy, while a kernel is still running.

Comment: i think u didn't get my  point...CUDA stream is not based on Ping pong that was used in DSPs few years back...i'm trying to implement this in CUDA so that,as i explained,stalls won't be there,stream may also prevent stalls,but whatever i'm proposing is something new i just want some inputs on how to implement it...coz here i'll have to scan the program for tht...

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you would be interested in the asynchronous host/device memory transfer capabilities of CUDA 4.0? You can overlap host/device memory transfers and kernels by using page-locked host memory. You could use this to...

1. Copy working set #1 & #2 from host to device.
2. Process #i, promote #i+1, and load #i+2 - concurrently.

So you could be streaming data in and out of the GPU and computing on it all at once (!). Please refer to the CUDA 4.0 Programming Guide and CUDA 4.0 Best Practices Guide for more detailed information. Good luck!

Comment: You don't need CUDA 4.0 to do that. Asynchronous host/device memory trasfers is an old story. What CUDA 4.0 does is an unified memory addressing accross several GPUs. The GPUs can now communicate without bothering the host.

Comment: Cool. I still think vanilla page-locked host memory can be used to do what he wants, though... Right?

Comment: I'm trying to apply Ping pong technique in GPU,the technique is mentioned below:

Comment: when we to want perform computation on large data ideally we'll send max data to GPU,perform computation,send it back to CPU i.e SEND,COMPUTE,SEND(back to CPU) now whn it sends back to CPU GPU has to stall,now my plan is given CU program,say it runs in entire global mem,i'll compel it to run it in half of the global mem so that rest of the half i can use for data prefetching,so while computation is being performed in one half simultaneously i cn prefetch data in otherhalf.so no stalls will be there..now tell me is it feasible to do?performance will be degraded or upgraded?should enhance..

Answer (score 0):

Cuda 6 will eliminate the need to copy, ie the copying will be automatic.
however you may still benefit from prefetching.

In a nutshell you want the data for the "next" computation transferring while you complete the current computation. to achieve that you need to have at least two threads on the CPU, and some kind of signalling scheme (to know when to send the next data). Chunking will of course play a big role and affect performance.

The above may be easier on an APU (CPU+GPU on the same die) as the need to copy is eliminated as both processors can access the same memory.

If you want to find some papers on GPU prefetching just use google scholar.